# HostGator mySQL connection time-outs after 10 seconds or so ---- how do I extend this?

Tags: mysql

for some reason when I open a connection the the Percona MySQL database on my HostGator website, after fetching the query, it will disconnect/ close the connection about 10 seconds later.

I typically wouldn't care, but HeidiSQL freezes up, preventing exporting or sorting the returned rows with it's UI unless I connect again.

Any thoughts on making the connection last longer? is it something I can do myself, or will it require a dedicated server or some upgrade? (I'm currently on a shared one). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like it may be the "wait" timeout on the MySQL connection.

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'
```

That's the amount of time (in seconds) that MySQL will leave the session (the database connection) open while it's idle, waiting for another statement to be issued. After this amount of time expires, MySQL can close the connection.

You should be able to change this for a session, to change the timeout to 5 minutes

```
SET wait_timeout = 300
```

Verify the setting with the `SHOW VARIABLES` statement again.

NOTE: This is per connection. It only affects the current session. Every new connection will inherit their own `wait_timeout` value from the global setting.

---

(This is only a guess. There's insufficient information in the question to make a precise diagnosis. It could be something other than MySQL server that's closing the database connection, e.g. it could be your connection pool settings (if you are using a connection pool).

Comment: This looks correct. My other connections have a 'wait_timeout' of 24 hours --- and this one has a 'wait_timeout' of 10 seconds. I guess I can increase that to 5 minutes or what-have-you. I just realized I have a separate process that opens 8 parallel connections to write data, and loops every 20 seconds, so given the max of 24 open connections with HostGator -- I may need to adjust this value at various times. Good to know though, thanks! EDIT: Or not if it only affects the current session/ connection.

Comment: Right. The 5 minutes was just an example, you can set it to whatever. Just don't set it too high... if your process crashes or ends without closing the connection, the MySQL server is going to keep it idle on the server side until it times out. Idle sessions aren't a problem, until you hit a system limit or a DBA specified upper limit on the number of connections allowed (such as `max_user_connections` for the mysql user.) The way I use `wait_timeout`, it's a backstop for cleaning up abandoned sessions  (our connections pools are configured to exercise long idle connections)